# Export 3D Model als standalone exe DMG viewer

Tags: game-engine, export, navigation

I'd like to publish 3D models as exe or DMG so my clients can open them as a stand-alone application for viewing. Basically, I'm looking for something like Sketchfab offline suitable for products I signed an NDA.  How can I do this with Blender? Do you know an easy alternative?
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Well, Blender 2.79 and under have stand-alone viewers built-in to their executables. You'd have to construct some sort of minimal interactive interface, or find a .blend with scripts already setup. If you've never used Blender before, it might take a bit of concerted effort. Good Luck.